# how to execute node js function from javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, single-sign-on

I am creating a java web application and i would need to access the machine's environment variables that opens my site, in this case i would use username and domain. These data help me to exploit single sign on technology.
I found that with js node obtaining such data is really easy, in fact two lines of code are enough:

```
console.log (process.env.USERNAME);
console.log (process.env.USERDNSDOMAIN);
```

Assuming you can install on each intranet node js machine, the question now is this: how can i run node js code from the usual javascript code that is contented on a web page?

Thank you all (and sorry for my english)

Comment: simple. you can't

Comment: There are restrictions built into all browsers that prevent access to the client side environment, you cannot access the local machine.  That said, you could run a Java Applet that gets the information from the client side and sends this to the server....I think!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do more than install NodeJS on each machine. It is like any other program installed on a computer that is also running a web browser: Not typically available for JS code to run.

You would also need to write a program which would get the information you needed and expose it over HTTP with cross-origin permission granted using CORS. Then you would need to configure each computer to run that program on startup.

Then you can use XMLHttpRequest to make an HTTP request from JavaScript in the page to `http://localhost:somePortNumber/your/node/js/api` to fetch the data.